# What is the usage of Private and Protected Constructors in Typescript

Tags: typescript, private-constructor

I noticed that in Typescript you can define constructor to be with any access modifier (private, protected, public). What will be the usage of this can someone give a valid example how to use private and protected constructors in Typescript ?

Example this is a valid code in Typescript:

```
class A
{
    private constructor()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just as in other languages the usage of this would be to not actually allow anyone (except for the class itself) to instantiate the class. This might be useful for example with a class that only has static method (a rare use case in Typescript as there are simpler ways to do this), or to allow a simple singleton implementation:

```
class A
{
    private constructor()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    private static _a :A
    static get(): A{
        return A._a || (A._a = new A())
    }
}
```

Or special initialization requirements that require using a factory function. FOr example async init:

```
class A
{
    private constructor()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    private init() :Promise<void>{} 
    static async create(): Promise<A>{
        let a = new A()
        await a.init();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think singletons don't make sense in JS because you should just create a literal object. However, factory functions are often why I use a private constructor

Comment: Factory functions are also an important use-cases for private constructors, maybe you should mention it in your answer.

Comment: @DavidCallanan I think my `create` example is exactly an example of a  factory function.  I added language to make that more clear.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Sorry, I was talking about the factory pattern that is used alongside dependency-injection, which actually wouldn't require private constructors, so you can ignore my comment haha

Answer (score 11):

This could be used for the [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

One of the approaches to this is not letting the external code create instances of the class at all. Instead, we use static accessor:

```
class SingletonExample {

    private constructor() {
        console.log('Instance created');
    }

    private static _instance: SingletonExample | undefined;

    public prop = 'value';

    public static instance() {
        if (this._instance === undefined) {
            // no error, since the code is inside the class
            this._instance = new SingletonExample();
        }
        return this._instance;
    }

}

const singleton = SingletonExample.instance(); // no error, instance is created
console.log(singleton.prop); // value
const oops = new SingletonExample(); // oops, constructor is private
```

Comment: new SingletonExample() works without any exceptions. console.log prints instance

Comment: Interesting. Could you add some details on how you're running this code?

Comment: @Roman: Typescript compiles to JavaScript, so by the time you're typing `new SingletonExample()` in the console you're calling JavaScript code, and since JavaScript doesn't have access modifiers you will not be prevented from making that call. The `Private`, `Protected`, and other TypeScript access modifiers only serve to protect your code at compile-time, not run-time.

Answer (score 1):

## Theory

Private constructors are used to enforce the singleton pattern.
In singleton pattern:

1. **You cannot directly instantiate an object from outside the class.**
2. **You will always have exactly one instance of a class.**

## Usage

Below is the example for using private constructor along with it's explanation.

#### Code:

```
class Admin{
    //The "instance" property below is the sole instance of the class 
    //throughout the app. It should be of type "className".
    private static instance:Admin;
    private id:string;
    private constructor(id:string){
    this.id=id;
    }
    static getInstance(id:string){
    //If the instance exists, don't create it, return the existing one.
    if(this.instance) return this.instance;
    //If instance doesn't exist,
    //create a new instance and initialize the id property.
    else {
        this.instance=new Admin(id);
        return this.instance;
    }
    }
    

}

const adminInstance=Admin.getInstance("A1");
console.log(adminInstance);
//Trying to instantiate the class twice below. The below instantiation will not fail 
//but the ID updation will fail and id will remain "A1"
const adminInstanceSecond=Admin.getInstance("A2");
console.log(adminInstanceSecond);
```

In the above example you can see that we forcefully try to instantiate our class
twice with two different value but console logs of the objects show A1 both the time.

#### Output:

```
 "First attempt",  Admin: {
  "id": "A1"
} 
 "Second attempt",  Admin: {
  "id": "A1"
}
```

Comment: #2 is not true. You could create a `public static` method which constructs such object and returns it. You can call this *factory method* as many times as you want, and thus many objects are created. For example, `private constructor() { } public static create(): A { return new A() }`

Answer (score 0):

Constructor - could be only public.

Public or private modifers are use in design time only. The purpose to use public or private is to hide private methods/props from outer "user". By default all methods/props are public. So when you declare something like this:

```
  export class MyClass{
    myProperty:string;
    constructor(){
       this.doJob();
    }

    doJob ():void{
       this.formatString(this.myProperty);
    }

    private formatString():string{
      return this.myProperty.toUpper();
    }
  }
```

In this example all props/methods are public and oly one private. So when you use this class somewhere you can write:

```
let a = new MyClass();
a.myProperty = "public";
a.doJob();
console.log(a.myProperty)
// PUBLIC <-- it become upper case by private method.
```

You have access to all public props/methods from other classes, but you can use private methods/props only inside of this class.

Protected methods/props are visible only for childs, whitch inherit this class.

Hope this will usefull.

Comment: "Constructor - could be only public" - could you explain, why "only"?

Comment: I think [it used to be true](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2341) that constructors can only be public (i.e. not private) -- in a later version of TypeScript (perhaps v2 and later) it's no longer true.

Comment: "Constructor - could be only public." This is certainly not true any more. If you fail to specify accessibility modifier on constructor, eslint will throw [an error](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-member-accessibility.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ts have a lot of sugars stuff for allow you design your arch in the way you prefer.

abstract protected private constructors are sugar modifier for replace some kind of singlethon design.

Example, one of my favorite singletons design pattern

(domainLike or ModuleLike)

```
/** Example of Domain Singlethon pattern */
export const MyClass = ( ( param?:any ) => {
    const staticProps = '';

    class MyClassBase {

    }
    class MyClassInstance extends MyClassBase {

    }

    /** Expose the modules/domain scope */
    return {

        staticProps,
        instance:new MyClassInstance(),

        /**
        // we can also easly expose class if needed
        MyClassBase,
        MyClassInstance,
        */

    };
} )();
class A extends MyClass {};// Cant
class B extends MyClassInstance {} // Cant
```

Some people prefer keep a kind of design with class for readability of the architecture,
So ts allow you do something like this if is at your taste !

```
abstract class MyClassBase {

    protected constructor(){}

}

class MyClassInstance extends MyClassBase {

    static readonly instance = new MyClassInstance();
    private constructor(){
        super();
    }

}

class C extends MyClass {}; // cant
class D extends MyClassInstance {} // cant
```

You have so many design pattern for all taste and need, ts just tries to give tools and design for all tastes, in this case, it allows you to design singleton's models to your liking and keep design of your app if you want or need this one.

Am waiting for final modifier where is will be awesome !